# using jint and jstring in android studio JNI function

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, native

I am working on an example of JNI in Android Studio, the goal it to generate a Random Value and pass it to a native function which will calculate its Square and return the result in this format ( Number/Square ).

I am passing the jint number as a parameter of the function, but the result is totally wrong (the result displayed is totaly wrong).
Here is my code :

Button Generating the number and calling the native function :

```
Button ButtonP = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        ButtonP .setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        Random r = new Random();
                        Integer valeur = 1 + r.nextInt(10 - 1);
                        Log.i("Tag", "Random Value BARRAK " + valeur);
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
                        tv.setText(stringFromJNIStop(valeur));
                    }
                });
```

The Native function:

```
public native String stringFromJNIStop(Integer nombre);
```

The implementation of the function in the cpp file:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_fr_utbm_testjniapplication1_MainActivity_stringFromJNIStop(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject, /* this */
        jint nombre) {
    jint CarreNombre = nombre*nombre;

    //Convertir le carré en un jstring
    char bufCarreNombre[64];
    sprintf(bufCarreNombre, "%d", CarreNombre);  // error checking omitted
    jstring jStringCarre = (*env).NewStringUTF(bufCarreNombre);
    //Le convertir en un char *
    const char *strCarre= (*env).GetStringUTFChars(jStringCarre,0);

    //Convertir le nombre en un jstring
    char bufNombre[64];
    sprintf(bufNombre, "%d", nombre);  // error checking omitted
    jstring jStringNombre = (*env).NewStringUTF(bufNombre);
    //Le convertir en char *
    const char *strNombre= (*env).GetStringUTFChars(jStringNombre,0);

    //Concaténer les deux
    char *concatenated;
    concatenated = (char *) malloc(strlen(strNombre) + strlen("/") + strlen(strCarre) + 1);
    strcpy(concatenated, strNombre);
    strcat(concatenated, "/");
    strcat(concatenated, strCarre);

    /* Create java string from our concatenated C string */
    jstring retval = (*env).NewStringUTF(concatenated);

    //need to release this string when done with it in order to
    //avoid memory leak
    (*env).ReleaseStringUTFChars(jStringNombre,strNombre);
    (*env).ReleaseStringUTFChars(jStringCarre,strCarre);
    /* Free the memory in concatenated */
    free(concatenated);
    return retval;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Native function:

```
public native String stringFromJNIStop(Integer nombre);
```

> The implementation of the function in the cpp file:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_fr_utbm_testjniapplication1_MainActivity_stringFromJNIStop(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject, /* this */
    jint nombre) {
```

This does not agree with your Java. You've changed it from `int` to `Integer` in the Java without regenerating your .h file, or you've changed or invented your .h file without reference to your .java file; or your .cpp file doesn't agree with your .h/.hpp file. Don't do this. Use `javah` to generate your .h/.hpp file, and redo it every time you change the native declaration(s) in your .java files, and make sure your .cpp file agrees with the .h/.hpp file. It should be:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_fr_utbm_testjniapplication1_MainActivity_stringFromJNIStop(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject, /* this */
    jobject nombre) {
```

where `nombre` refers to an `Integer`. However it would be better, and would always have been better, to define your Java native method as:

```
public native String stringFromJNIStop(int nombre);
```

which will now agree with your existing .cpp.

Also your .cpp should `#include` your .h/.hpp. Then you wouldn't have needed `extern "C"` or `JNI_EXPORT` or `JNI_CALL`, and the compiler may have detected the signature disagreement between .cpp and .h/.hpp.

Comment: "redo it every time you change the native declaration(s) in your .java files": You should be able to do this by adding a step to your Java project build and, with the resulting header under source control, you'd know soon enough when your change is only half done.

Answer (score -2):

After some reflexion, problem was resolved, in fact, in order to implement the JNI function using jint, we have to adopt the exact conversion rules in the JAVA part, so instead of declaring the random value as an integer, we must declare it as a long ! so we must work as follows :

```
long valeur = 1 + r.nextInt(10 - 1);
```

Comment: That's not the problem at all.

Comment: @EJP This "answer" might be the most perverse non-fix I've even seen.  It probably seems to "work" because the `long` value is the same size as a pointer on the target architecture, so the passed and expected arguments match size-wise, and this "fix" is using the pointer value JNI uses to pass the Java `Integer` object as a "random" `long` value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't see how it could even have compiled unchanged. You can't autobox `long` to `Integer`.

Comment: @EJP No,autobox needed. The `Integer` as a `jobject` to the C function will be a pointer after all the `typedef`'s are unraveled. I'd bet the Java and C code still don't match - just as they don't match in the question. But a likely 64-bit platform that `jobject` value will nicely match the size of the `jlong` in the "fix".  And the address values in pointers passed by the JVM to JNI functions are in my experience different enough values to mimic a random value, at least to pass a casual inspection. So, perversely, the change to 'jlong' appears to "work" for all the wrong reasons.

Comment: @EJP (cont) I suspect, given `public native String stringFromJNIStop(Integer nombre);` and the "fixed" `Java_fr_utbm_testjniapplication1_MainActivity_stringFromJNIStop(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject, /* this */
        jlong nombre)` (note it's `jlong` here) that `nombre` gets the *address* of the Java `Integer` object, passed as a `jobject`.  Since `jlong` and `jobject` are likely both 64-bit values, it "works".  It's like swimming through a shark tank covered in blood and making to to the other side, though. Just cuz you made it don't make it safe.

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is all irrelevant. You can't pass a `long` to a Java function that is declared as accepting an `Integer`, whether it is native or otherwise. You could pass an `int` and have it autoboxed. `long` does not autobox to `Integer`. The code in this answer does not compile unless there were further changes.

Comment: @EJP Again, there's no autoboxing .You are assuming that the Java `native` declaration matches the actual C definition.  In this case, it doesn't.  Again - there's no autoboxing.  OP modified his **C** code (actually C++, but it's `extern "C"`...) from expecting a `jint` to expecting a `jlong`. If, as implied, he did that *without changing the **Java** declaration* from expecting an `Integer`, the JVM will pass an `Integer` as a `jobject` - a pointer that's almost certainly a 64-bit value, which the now-`jlong` in the native function treats as a random value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sigh. I am assuming nothing except what is written here. *You* are assuming that 'OP modified his C code ... from expecting a `jint` to expecting a `jlong`'. Where does it say that? His code in this answer doesn't compile. You cannot call `public native String stringFromJNIStop(Integer nombre)` with a `long` argument. You can call it with an `int` argument, which causes autoboxing. I am perfectly aware that his Java definition doesn't match his native defintion, and that is exactly what I stated at some length in my answer.